# DuplicateFileException with Android Studio when trying to import 2 jar files

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import two jar files to my Android Studio Project. But when i try to run the code. I get the following Error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate
files copied in APK META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA

File1: A:\Uni-mora-sem4\IOT\Project\ClientApp\AndroidClientV2\app\libs
\org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar

File2: A:\Uni-mora-sem4\IOT\Project\ClientApp\AndroidClientV2\app\libs\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar
```

Gradle File is as Follows.........

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "iot.dulanga.com.androidclientv2"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar')

}
```

Any ideas why I get this error ??

Comment: Check my answer below and see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because both the `jar`s are containing `META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA` and thus while packing the `apk`, duplication is arising.

So try to add this in the app's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
   packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
   }
}
```